# p:selectBooleanCheckbox *look only* shifted after adding a row to a p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectbooleancheckbox

I have a `p:dataTable`. In this table, I have a checkbox in a column. This is the code:

```xhtml
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox 
    value="#{var.selected}"
    itemLabel="#{var.description}" 
/>
```

After I add a row and update the whole table, the selected checkboxes **after** the row inserted have the checks shifted up! **But** it's only a graphical problem! The checkboxes that now appears unchecked are **yet** checked, because I show other things in the row if the checkbox is selected. On the contrary, the checkbox that now appear checked do **not** show the additional components.

I checked the html, and the classes and attributes that make them checked disappears. But debugging the backend I see that the in the list connected to the table, after the add, **all** the items have the expected value.

This is a minimal reproducible example:
https://ufile.io/6a60kxpn

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JasperdeVries I found that the problem is due to `immediate="true"` to the button that adds rows to the table. The problem is that without that, I can't add rows without first compile the entire table.....

Comment: @JasperdeVries I added the minimal reproducible example.  You can see that without `immediate="true"` all works, but I need it to not trigger the form validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but I solved putting `process="@this"` to the `actionButton`s. If someone can explain me why, I'll accept the answer.